# Getting errors installing Tensorflow GPU

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I was earlier working with the CPU only version of tensorflow. I tried installing the GPU version now using [this](https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-cuda-gpu-tensorflow-deep-learning-tutorial/) link.

But I think I messed up.

When I try to do `import tensorflow` it gives the following message:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because a wrong version of cuda is installed : check `/usr/local/` for the versions of cuda that are installed and if it matches with the version in the Tensorflow error. If it both versions don't match, you'll have to either install another version of cuda or Tensorflow.

Another reason could be because of missing environment variables (as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1501)). 
Try this :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
```

Comment: I entered the 2 commands in the terminal. It didn't work out.

Comment: Are you sure cuda 7.5 is properly installed and located in the paths stated in these commands?

Comment: In the /usr/local folder, I see two folders. One is cuda-8.0 (type: folder) and the other is cudo(type:link to folder)

Comment: Looks like your versions of tensorflow and cuda aren't compatible - try downgrading to cuda 7.5 first. You could also try to find a version of tensorflow which is compatible with cuda 8 (I think later versions are) but you might run into more trouble

Comment: So, what do I need to do? Just delete the cuda folder from /usr/local and then download cuda 7.5 and then copy cudnn?

Comment: Yes you could try that

Comment: Yes I was able to successfully install it by first deleting the old cuda folder and then installing cuda 7.5. Please edit your answer so that I may accept it.